# can't get 2> to work on g++ command line on Ubuntu update

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, stderr

On a remote server that was updated with a newer version of Ubuntu, when I try to redirect stderr it won't work.  Using putty from windows, but I've done it on the old server all the time.

`g++ filename 2> whatever.txt`

just says

> g++: error: 2: No such file or directory

When I click the up arrow to bring it back it shows the command with a space between 2 and > as:

`g++ filename 2 > whatever.txt`

What the heck is going on here?  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try it while directly logged into the Ubuntu machine or if you use a different terminal program like MobaXterm or if Windows, the DOS shell or Powershell?

Comment: yes, it turns out the server defaulted to CSH which doesn't support 2>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the shell was `csh` which doesn't support that.

To find if you're using it use:
`echo $0`

Comment: Note that `csh` supports `cmd >& file` to redirect both stdout and stderr to `file` (zsh and bash did copy that from csh; though there that  overlaps with the `>& 2` Bourne syntax)